# XML symfony data retrieval

Tags: xml, symfony

I have a XML file in which I saved some product details: ID, name, price

How can I display these rows in a table?
Should I use doctrine? Where should I put the XML file? In public and then install assets?

Here is my products.xml

```
<products>
<product>
    <id>2222</id>
    <manufacturer>AMINE</manufacturer>
    <name>*AMINE    123    185/65 R15 88 T</name>
    <additional>AUSLAUF</additional>
    <price>74.24</price>
    <availability>4</availability>
    <product_image>http://media2.tyre24.de/images/tyre/330-R-w300-h300-br1.jpg</product_image>
</product>
<product>
    <id>3333</id>
    <manufacturer>AMINE</manufacturer>
    <name>*AMINE    456    185/65 R15 88 T</name>
    <additional>AUSLAUF</additional>
    <price>74.24</price>
    <availability>4</availability>
    <product_image>http://media2.tyre24.de/images/tyre/330-R-w300-h300-br1.jpg</product_image>
</product>
<product>
    <id>3333</id>
    <manufacturer>AMINE</manufacturer>
    <name>*AMINE    789    185/65 R15 88 T</name>
    <additional>AUSLAUF</additional>
    <price>74.24</price>
    <availability>4</availability>
    <product_image>http://media2.tyre24.de/images/tyre/330-R-w300-h300-br1.jpg</product_image>
</product>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'simplexml_load_file($url);' function. This function will convert an XML file into a SimpleXMLElement object, then output keys and elements of the object.

After this 'json_decode(json_encode((array)$var_name),1)' this function will convert the that object to an json object. By using this josn object we can do what ever we want.

```
 public function functionNameAction(){
    // Write your code
    try {
        $simpleXMLElementObject = simplexml_load_file($file_url);
        $xml_josn_object = json_decode(json_encode((array)$simpleXMLElementObject),1);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        // Handle the exception 
    }

    // Render your template and pass this $xml_josn_object into the template and do what ever you want in that template
}
```

For reference just [Look this](https://php.net//manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: I got this working but I can't display in twig page !!!, how can I loop and display these element ?

Comment: Nothing difficult to display. Just find out the attribute name and loop it.                              //In twig just write like
     {% for lift in feed.LiftStatusMorning.LiftStatus %}
            <div>{{ lift.Lift }}</div>  
     {% endfor %}